# jquery text toggle onclick

Tags: jquery, toggle

This is probably a stupid question, but I've only started learning, so please be patient :) ... why does this text toggling not work please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  textSwap();
  $("#showHi").on("click", textSwap);
  $("#showBye").on("click", textSwap);
});
var isHi = false; 
function textSwap() {  
  if (isHi) {
    $("#text").html("<a href='#' id='showHi'>Bye</a>");
  }
  if (!isHi) {
    $("#text").html("<a href='#' id='showBye'>Hi</a>");
  }
  isHi = !isHi;
}
```

and:

```
<div id="text">some text</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6teotdt/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help @Sinisa Bobic your code works well and is simple, I didn't know I was using the syntax incorrectly?

Comment: But @Bruno Carletti's approach with deprecated code works too, so I do not know what is happening - is it deprecated or is something else at play... So not sure which answer to accept!

Comment: You are not using it incorrectly, since they removed .live binding you cannot bind something which not exist so you bind click on body only if you click on element specified on this way, check jQuery manual for details... In my personal opinion better is to bind only once like I did instead of binding in each function call even if it is working correctly (on old jQuery version that can cause problems, not tested in new)

Comment: If you want to use @Bruno Carletti's solution, to skip possible problem with bindings each time you must also do .off

Comment: Also, please use else instead of two ifs, sorry for spamming comments...

Comment: Perfect @Sinisa Bobic, I finally got it thanks to your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no anymore **.live** in jQuery (or it's Deprecated not 100% sure), you must use **.on** on this way and it will work

```
$("body").on("click", "#showHi", textSwap);
$("body").on("click", "#showBye", textSwap);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happen because you overwrite the original HTML with de $("#text").html...

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  textSwap();
});
var isHi = false; 
function textSwap() { 
    console.log(isHi);
  if (isHi) {
    $("#text").html("<a href='#' id='showHi'>Bye</a>");
    $("#showHi").on("click", textSwap);
  }
  if (!isHi) {
    $("#text").html("<a href='#' id='showBye'>Hi</a>");
    $("#showBye").on("click", textSwap);  
  }
  isHi = !isHi;
}
```

Another and simple way to do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/07enc391/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  textSwap();
  var isHi = false;
  $("#showHi").on("click", textSwap);
  $("#showBye").on("click", textSwap);
});
function textSwap() {  
  if (isHi) {
    $("#text").html("<button id='showHi'>Bye</button>");
  }
  else{
    $("#text").html("<button id='showBye'>Hi</button>");
  }
  isHi = !isHi;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't explain.The problem is in both versions that the second time I try to toggle it does nothing, so can toggle Hi to Bye, but Bye does not toggle back to Hi